# How to destroy previous activity when you jumped to next activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have activity A, having timer thread. after 5 sec it jumps to activity B via intent. how to destroy activity A when you are on activity B so that back button don't let you go back to activity A.

Comment: "having timer thread" I bet you do not need your own thread. try   `postRunableDelayed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the activity backstack.

```
intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

just call `finish()` when you make the intent from A to B

Comment: I did, but then timer thread does't work. it also destroy with finish() i guess.

Comment: public static A a;
onCreate()
{
    a = this;
}
now use that object in another Activity to finish first-activity like this,

on B activity onCreate()
{//when your timer is finished...
    A.a.finish();
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Waiting(5);
}

public class Waiting {
    Timer timer;

    public Waiting(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new WaitingTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class WaitingTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi, I'm waiting here!");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity1.class);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            timer.cancel();
        }

    }
}
 }
```

**MainActivity1.java**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
  }

}
```